# Did Dedekind prove this lemma about posets (or an equivalent)?

Tags: mathematics, set-theory

Here's an easy lemma:

*Any poset $(S, \preceq)$ is order-isomorphic to a subset of the powerset $\mathcal{P}(S)$ ordered by set-inclusion.*

I seem to recall having seen this attributed to Dedekind.

Am I right that Dedekind proves this little result? And if so, where does he do it?

Comment: I'm not quite sure about the relevance of this question to the history of mathematics. [See this post I made](http://meta.hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/143/are-questions-of-the-type-did-person-x-do-action-y-on-topic)

Answer (score 3):

I think that the source is Richard Dedekind's [Was sind und was sollen die Zahlen ?](https://archive.org/details/wassindundwasso00dedegoog) (Vieweg: Braunschweig, 1888).

I quote from the English translation : [THE NATURE AND MEANING OF NUMBERS](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/21016/21016-pdf.pdf), (The Open Court Publishing Co., 1901) :

> **98. Definition** [page 37]. If $n$ is any number, then will we denote by $Z_n$ the system [set] of all numbers that are not greater than $n$ [...].
>
> **106. Theorem** [page 38]. If $m < n$, then is  $Z_m$ proper part of  $Z_n$ and conversely.

---

I've found it through :

- Gregory Moore, *Zermelo's Axiom of Choice : Its Origin Development and Influence* (1982), page 26.

We can easily generalise it to a poset $M$ whatever, defining the mapping :

> > $\pi : a \to M_a$, for any $a \in M.$

where $M_a = \{ x \in M : x \le a \}$

Comment: I suspect you are right that (106) in his truly great paper is the nearest Dedekind gets. But is that really enough to warrant attributing Dedekind the generalization to [what we now call] any poset? Perhaps not ...?

Comment: @PeterSmith - I agree; with insight, it is very easy to "generalize" it --- now that we have one hundred years of development of set theory and abstract algebra (due also to Dedekind).